# Stepper motor control with RPi 3B+

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I want to control 2 stepper motors with RPI.
I wrote a loop with HIGH, LOW and delay.
When I increase the speed the waveform changes and the driver(Rtelligent R86) stops the motor (NEMA 34).
The stable frequency is still slow.
When using the GPIO.PWM() method, the speed is higher, but I can't control the number of steps, acceleration and deceleration.

Do I need HW PWM or can SW be enough?
Is there a framework or best practice that I can use to control the number of pulses and acceleration?

Comment: You don't use PWM for a stepper motor

Comment: @Milliways People probably use PWM as it is easiest tool provided by the software library they are using.  Have a look at pigpio waves and/or wave chains.  They may be suitable.  http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#wave_add_generic Also have a look at lg pulses.  http://abyz.me.uk/lg/py_lgpio.html#tx_pulse

Comment: "wave_add_generic" seems good as I can control the acceleration, frequency and number of steps as well. And what's even better, in case of a mistake, I know the remaining steps of the wave.
Today I wrote the code based on the "wave_add_generic" example. I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: @joan I get [errno 104] message over 4000 pulses, and "No more OOL for waveform" if I split to 2000 pulses.